# Custom DialogFragment with different animations for different orientations

Tags: android, android-animation, android-dialogfragment

I have a custom [`DialogFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) with a custom in/out animation set via `Theme`. It has different animations for portrait and landscape orientations. Problem is when changing orientation when the dialog is shown. It plays animation corresponding to the orientation the device had when dialog was created. Is there any way to reload the animation so it takes proper one from resources?

I've tried to set the animation again in [`onConfigurationChanged`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29), but didn't work.

*CustomDialogFragment.java*

```
public class CustomDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public int getTheme() {
        return R.style.CustomKeypadTheme;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        getDialog().getWindow().setWindowAnimations(R.style.CustomAnimation_Window);
    }
}
```

*styles.xml*

```
<style name="CustomKeypadTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Panel">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/CustomAnimation.Window</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomAnimation.Window" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/custom_animation_in</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/custom_animation_out</item>
</style>
```

*custom_animation_in.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="@dimen/custom_anim_deltaX"
        android:fromYDelta="@dimen/custom_anim_deltaY"
        android:toXDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="0"
        android:duration="400" />

</set>
```

*custom_animation_out.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="@dimen/custom_anim_deltaX"
        android:toYDelta="@dimen/custom_anim_deltaY"
        android:duration="400" />

</set>
```

`custom_anim_deltaX` and `custom_anim_deltaY` have different values defined for portrait and landscape.